# TcxShellListView - Sorting - C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6, rad-studio

I am using a 'TcxShellListView'(ExpressEditorsLibrary 6.59) for displaying the files in a directory. I have the following question:

Is the sorting of TcxShellListView possible?  The only possibility I could find is to use the 'OnCompare' event. But, can someone give me an idea of how to implement the sorting functionality in this event?

I am using C++ Builder 6 in Windows 10.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem from the following thread 
[Solution](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/s19704/tcxshelllistview-vsreport-view-style-add-the-capability-to-sort-items)

Also, further explanation is provided by the Embarcadero support team in this link:
[Explanation to the solution](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t863415/sorting-tcxshelllistview)

The sample project given by the support team in the first link will help in implementing the sorting functionality in a TcxShellListView with the help of Jcl libraries.